# How to add a html image to form request before submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-io, request

The html code is like this:

```
<img src="1245454101215" id='generatedImage' />

<form id='myForm'>
  <input type='text' />

  <input type=submit />
</form>
```

And the js code is like this:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function () {
    $('#myForm').append(
        $('<input/>').attr('type', 'file').attr('name', 'imagePreprocessed').attr('src', $('#generatedImage').src)
    )
});
$("#myForm").submit();
```

But isn't working.

**[edited]**

Sorry for my english.

I want to intercept a non-ajax submit form and insert an image to the form then do a normal submit

Comment: can you please elaborate your question ? It seems you have just added 2 blocks of code and saying it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery objects don't have a `src` property. Try this:

```
$('#generatedImage').attr('src')
```

instead of:

```
$('#generatedImage').src
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, try this instead

`$('#myForm').append('<input type="file" name="imagePreprocessed" src="' + $('#generatedImage').attr('src') + '">');`

Comment: When I do that, the file input is appended but without file.

Comment: You can't really upload files like that. The src tag is just a URL pointer. You need a lot more to upload a file the way you want!

Comment: Hi Andreas, can you tell me how I can do that

Comment: Create a new question for that!